# How can I get all the modules of node.js to raspberry pi. Please see the link below, I need this exact thing for a raspberry

Tags: linux, node.js, kali

SO I have to run a custom electron app which is running on AMD device after installing node.js from this site,

https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/410/how-to-install-node-js-in-kali-linux

Is there a way I can get this entire thing for Kali running on a Raspberry Pi. I have tried changing the node.js file to that of an ARM device but then it doesn't run the next step "./configure" after that and also just stops tar process in between showing error " too many arguments ". Please suggest a way to get this exact setup on Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Are you trying to **build** nodejs for raspberry pi?

Comment: @JaromandaX I have software i got from someone which works on linux kali on AMD devices and i want to run it on kali running on raspberry Pi. When I install nodejs and do a electron-rebuild gives a long list of error and when i run the software just shows the window without anything inside it

Comment: Oh, ok, didn't really understand what was happening in the link - that seems to be how to install node.js - which seems extremely complicated compared to how I do it - re-reading it again, that link seems to be "how to build nodejs" ... nothing about "electron" at all

Comment: To be honest, I find it unlikely that you get `tar` errors when running the `./configure` step - seeing as `./configure` does nothing with `tar` as far as I can see - I think you need to check you've typed `tar xzvf node-latest.tar.gz && cd node-v*` correctly - i.e. can you see a folder called `node-v9.9.0` ?

Comment: @JaromandaX I am done with the nodejs installation now I guess but the app shows just a blank screen. Now I think maybe it is because it was a x86 native application and I am trying to make it run on ARM. Although it still loads the app but just a blank screen

Comment: `I am done with the nodejs installation now` - well, the only thing you asked for in the question deals with installing nodejs!! but yes, a native x86 application won't run on ARM architecture - but this native x86 app was "created" using electron? so, create it on the Rpi using electron

Comment: I have no idea how to work with electron. I am a network guy who has to use this app on ARM but the only thing it does it loads a white screen. I have installed electron, npm, node still nothing positive. electron-rebuild gives a list of red colored errors. @JaromandaX

Comment: seriously, if there is a truly native program involved, regardless of how it was built, then it (usually) won't run in a different operating system, let alone on a completely different architecture